# QuickTime Player Green Screen

Tags: imac, screen, screen-capture, quicktime

I am trying to record a video with Quicktime Player but whenever I record it shows a green screen.
When I try to watch the video when I record the screen:

[image]
P.S I am using an iMac...

Comment: Try using a third party screen recorder. Unfortunately, although Quick Time is nicely integrated and really simple, it's screen recording feature is a MAJOR resource hog. Screen flow makes a higher detail recording using 15% of my CPU than QT can make with 90% utilization.

Comment: Try the solution I posted here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87613/quicktime-records-a-green-screen/103041#103041

Comment: You didn't mention what source you're trying to record. If it's an external card, you need to tell us what model, what format the video is, etc. Green like that could happen if you're trying to capture an unsupported SDI signal, among other things.